# How to remove double box - Angular UI Select

Tags: angular-ui-select

I get double boxes for drop down list in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.  How can I remove the box below?

```
<ui-select ng-required="isPriceChoiceExist" name="size" ng-model="selected.productPriceId">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Size">{{$select.selected.displayDesc}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="s.priceId as s in product.regularPriceChoices | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="s.displayDesc | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was introduced when I added angular-mobile-ui [Angular Mobile UI](http://mobileangularui.com/).  The bootstrap class `.dropdown-menu { display: none}` is overwritten with `.dropdown-menu { display: block}` in angular-mobile-ui.